# Apache: Prevent .htaccess banned IP from recording errors in logs

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, logging, ip-banning

On my Apache-hosted Ruby on Rails website, an IP address (always identical) from Russia was hammering the website every twenty minutes, based on the path requests I think it's trying to seek out comment forms to submit spam comments onto.

Anyway, I did the following in my .htaccess file to completely boot them off while allowing everyone else...

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from XX.XX.XX.XXX
Allow from all
```

So it worked, their IP no longer shows up in my Rails logs and they can't access the site. However, the error log for the website in the /var/log/apache2 folder continues to rack up the same error by the banned IP...

```
[Thu Jun 30 09:11:37 2011] [error] [client XX.XX.XX.XXX] client denied by server configuration: /srv/[...]
```

It's obvious what the error is for, but I don't think it's necessary to keep recording that this IP was blocked, I want to keep my errors file clean for other legit errors. How can I stop the logs from recording this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from within apache. The easiest method would be to send the logs to a filter script rather than straight to a file.